# Change WooCommerce add to cart text for specific tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a function to change the Add to Cart text on a woocommerce button but only if the product in question has a specific tag. ie if the product has the tag "preorder" the button text changes to "Pre Order Now"

Changing the text globally can be achieved with this;

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for that particular term with [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term).

```
    //For single product page
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' ); // 2.1 +
    function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        global $product;
        if ( has_term( 'preorder', 'product_cat', $product->ID ) ) :
            return __( 'Pre order Now!', 'woocommerce' );
        endif;
    }
    //For Archive page
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' ); // 2.1 +
    function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
        if ( has_term( 'preorder', 'product_cat', $product->ID ) ) :
            return __( 'Pre order Now!', 'woocommerce' );
        else:
            return __( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' );
        endif;
    }
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: Thank you, I have to change product_cat to product_tag and add an else statement for the first part but worked perfectly then, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but try something along the following lines:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
/**
* custom_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart
*/
function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {

global $product;

$product_tag = $product->product_tag;

switch ( $product_tag ) { 
  case 'preorder':
    return __( 'Pre order Now!', 'woocommerce' );
  break;
  default:
    return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Basically what you're trying to do is do a conditional where you check if the product tag is "preorder". I am not sure if this exact code would work if there are multiple tags.

Edit:
You might have to use this filter to change it on the product page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your child theme function.php file

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 
 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text_archives' );  
function woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text_archives() {
return __( 'Add to Cart Button Text', 'woocommerce' );
```

Answer (score -2):

You can fix it by adding a few lines of codes in `functions.php`:

```
// Change the add to cart text on single product pages

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text’, ‘woo_custom_cart_button_text' ); // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    return __( 'ADD TO CART', 'woocommerce' );
}

//Change the add to cart text on product archives
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' ); // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
    return __( 'ADD TO CART', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

http://visupporti.com/woocommerce-how-to-change-add-to-cart-text/