# How do I change the select options text to view details when WooCommerce Deposits is active?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On shop page when you have WooCommerce deposits activated, the add to cart becomes select options. How do I change the text to view details? There are also items that are just labeled add to cart, I want those to stay the same.

EDIT: I tried this code

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );            // < 2.1
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {

    return __( 'View Details', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

But this only changes the "Add to Cart" text. WooCommerce deposits changes the "Add to cart" text to "Select Options" if deposits are enabled. How do I change the "Select Options" to "View Details". Basically "Select Options" is like "Read More" on the product archives.
This is the code I think when I use inspect element on it. Edited out the website name and product name.

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://example.com/product/item-name/" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="60973" data-product_sku="CUS-MARF44" class="product_type_simple  ajax_add_to_cart">Select options</a>
```

I found this in the WooCommerce Deposit Files

```
/**
 * Add to cart text
 */
public function add_to_cart_text( $text ) {
    global $product;

    if ( is_single( $product->id ) ) {
        return $text;
    }

    if ( ! WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::deposits_enabled( $product->id ) ) {
        return $text;
    }

    $deposit_type = WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::get_deposit_type( $product->id );
    if ( WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::deposits_forced( $product->id ) ) {
        if ( 'plan' !== $deposit_type ) {
            return $text;
        }
    }

    $text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_deposits_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce-deposits' ) );

    return $text;
}
```

What should I add in the functions.php so that I would not need to edit the code in the core file?

Comment: put in what you tried please....

Comment: Added what I tried and some new information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066759/change-woocommerce-add-to-cart-text-for-specific-tag
Seems that this is a good answer but where do I find the has_term for deposits?

Answer (score 0):

I found the code for this in the plugin files like so.

```
/**
 * Add to cart text
 */
public function add_to_cart_text( $text ) {
    global $product;

    if ( is_single( $product->id ) ) {
        return $text;
    }

    if ( ! WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::deposits_enabled( $product->id ) ) {
        return $text;
    }

    $deposit_type = WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::get_deposit_type( $product->id );
    if ( WC_Deposits_Product_Manager::deposits_forced( $product->id ) ) {
        if ( 'plan' !== $deposit_type ) {
            return $text;
        }
    }

    $text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_deposits_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce-deposits' ) );

    return $text;
}
```

I can edit this code in the plugin to change the Select Options to View Details but what is a better code in the functions.php, so that when the plugin updates, the changes won't be reverted

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here (based on the code helpfully provided by @anjxed) is add a filter, like this:

```
// Change "Select Options" message for Deposits 
add_filter('woocommerce_deposits_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_select_options_text');
function my_custom_select_options_text($text) {
    $text = __( 'Register', 'woocommerce-deposits' );
    return $text;
}
```